# Symfony subquery with getDQL throws error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony4, query-builder

I am trying to convert below query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name d WHERE d.number != '' ORDER BY d.stop_time DESC ) AS p GROUP BY p.number
```

with symfony query builder as below =>

```
$sub = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$sub->select('d')
  ->from($this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityClass)->getName(), 'd')
  ->where("d.number != ''")
  ->orderBy('d.time', 'DESC');

  $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('p')
    ->from($sub->getDQL(),'p')
    ->groupBy('p.number');
```

I am getting below error =>

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 14: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'SELECT'
```

Please correct query if anything wrong in it.

Comment: What happens not is on your second select the sql looks like `SELECT SELECT * FROM d...`. I don't see what you are trying to do there but it looks like you don't need a sub query to do a simple group by.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer

```
$sub = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$sub->select('d.id')
  ->from($this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityClass)->getName(), 'd')
  ->where("d.number != ''")
  ->orderBy('d.time', 'DESC');

  $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('p')
    ->from($this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityClass)->getName(), 'p')
->where("p.id IN (".$sub->getDQL().")")
    ->groupBy('p.number');
```